# IBM Quantum Experience: simulation not running on IBMQ_16_melbourne

Tags: ibm-q-experience

What is this dedicated use of IBMQ_16_melbourne? I am trying to run a simulation but it is not running. Is there any way to run the simulations? When is the backend coming online again for normal users?

Comment: I assume you are using the Circuit Composer in the IBM Q Experience? When you hit run, and the pop up that lets you set the backend and the amount of shots comes up, a pop up window should come up with the available backends and different amount of shots. These should both be drop down boxes that allow you to change the selected device and amount of shots. If you click on the device, does a drop down window with the other available backends appear?

Comment: There might currently be a problem with melbourne, submitting a simple epr pair circuit through python has been running for at least 3 hours, but it's marked as "running"

Answer (score 1):

First you will need a [IBM Q experience](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/) account if you do not have one. Using the token listed under your profile you will import the IBMQ package, save your account, and execute the program on an available backend.

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.save_account('MY_TOKEN', 'URL')
IBMQ.load_accounts(hub=None) #Run everytime to load your account info saved locally
IBMQ.backends() #Prints available backends
# Or select from least busy backend
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
large_enough_devices = IBMQ.backends(filters=lambda x: x.configuration().n_qubits < 10 and
                                                   not x.configuration().simulator)
backend = least_busy(large_enough_devices)
print("The best backend is " + backend.name())
```

**Now execute**

```
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
shots = 1024        
max_credits = 3   
job_exp = execute(qc, backend=backend, shots=shots, max_credits=max_credits)
job_monitor(job_exp)
```

(Where qc is a parameter accepting the quantum circuit to be executed)
Be sure to check the [qiskit tutorials](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/basics/1_getting_started_with_qiskit.ipynb) for and IBM Q experience to learn more. These backend servers are pretty much always available and you can check the status of them on the IBM Q experience with your account.

Answer (score 1):

The device is currently undergoing planned maintenance to update the control electronics.